# Local IP Over Internet - PPPoE connection type - tried using noip as well

Tags: internet, webcam, pppoe, ddns

I have a Raspberry Pi which I want to try to access over the Internet. Its local IP address is `192.168.0.100`. I am using an IP webcam on my old phone which I want to see over the Internet - its local IP address and port is `192.168.0.105:8080`.

I have a connection from the local broadband provider which is a PPPoE connection type with a username and password:

[image: WAN Connection Type]

I'm currently using a TP-Link TL-WR720N 150Mbps Wireless N router.

Things I have already tried:

- As my IP is not static, I registered on noip.com and registered a hostname which has been configured in the DDNS of router as well.
- I have added both the above IP addresses to my router's virtual servers.
- I have tried my best changing all the options but I could not access these over the Internet.

Below are the few screenshots which might help:

[image: DDNS and virtual server]

Comment: We need more details about the exact meaning of "I could not access these over internet". What exact error do you get when you try?

Comment: Lets take example of raspberryPi   i can ssh or vnc from my mac using local address 192.168.0.100    now since i have given noip hostname i am trying to access the host just10minutes.noip.me   i cannot connect to it. I tried doing remote desktop connection from windows but i could not connect i get the default error message. one of these option either network is down,  or system is not switched on

Comment: You should tell us what error appears on your screen when you try from the internet. The fact that ssh and vnc work in your LAN is irrelevant. There is no such thing like a default error message.

Comment: Hope below is will explain more
1. I switched on Ip Webcamera app on android phone local address 192.168.0.105:8080
2. added 192.168.0.105 to virtual server with port 8080
3. restarted router
4.Now on my another mobile which is differnt internet connection than my home network  trying to access just10minute.noip.me:8080
5. Expectation was i will see the same page which i see when i type 192.168.0.105:8080 on my home network
6. Getting error - 
This webpage is not available  Err_Connection_timed_out

Comment: Most residential network agreements have a prohibition against running servers on your network buried somewhere in the fine print, and some residential ISPs actively block ports which are commonly used to run servers. You can try to set this up with a different, unusual port number. You should check the [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) to make sure you don't step on a port used by something else.

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual Server you configured in your router only opens port 3389 of your RaspberryPI. You might be able to use rdesktop with that, but you can't browse your IP camera until you open its 8080 port on your router as well.

You should add a new Virtual Server in your router configuration like this:

```
Service    IP Address       Protocol    Status
8080       192.168.0.105    All         Enabled
```

EDIT: since both the services do not work from the internet even if you have already added them to the router configuration, my suspect is that something is blocking all inbound traffic, regardless of the configured virtual servers. It could be the firewall configuration of your router or your ISP to blame.

Comment: I have done that already as mentioned in my comment point 2.

i observed now I  also can ping my address just10minutes.noip.me   but unable to access what i want to see on browser :(

Comment: You're right, my fault. Does rdesktop work from the internet to your RaspberryPI?

Comment: no rdesktop does not run from internet,  i can do it locally using local ip.

Comment: You should always update your question with new information like the one you have added ports 8080 for both IP addresses to your virtual server list. To what is the firewall on your raspberryPI set?

Answer (score 0):

First steps I would take is to ensure that just10minute.noip.me is resolving correctly to your internet connection. I would go to http://ping.eu/nslookup/action.php?atype=3&host_w=just10minutes.noip.me

As that seems to show the correct ip address, the next step I'd try is to set up the raspberry pi address in the Forwarding->DMZ and see if you can get any response. http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/ is another useful resource to determine what ports are open.

I would also check to see if there is a firewall running on the Pi, such as ip tables. In initial steps I would stop that altogether. Then if that allows access, I'd work on the configuration for iptables.

Comment: my host name is just10minutes.noip.me  there is a 's' after minute. when i do ping to this i am able to ping from outside network

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through similar requirement I can say that most reliable, secure and consistent way would be running an OpenVPN server in the cloud and then setting up Raspberry Pi as a gateway for the local network so you can access any device on the network RPI is part of from anywhere in the world. I am personally using Amazon Lightsail and it costs me around 4$ a month but any cloud service would do the job.
Setting up openvpn server is very easy thanks to angristan install script and shouldn't take more than an hour to complete.
This solution will not only overcome any restriction put in place by ISP or router but will do it in a most secure way without port forwarding.

This is a good resource to start from: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/